# Slack & Salesforce - Rest API - Outgoing webhook

Tags: salesforce, slack

I am trying to connect to Salesforce Apex using POST. Slack has this pluggin, Outgoing Webhook which sends to a URL a POST request.

I have already created an APEX class to handle the request,

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/test/accounts/*')
global with sharing class REST_slackAccount {

    @HttpGet
    global static void doGet() {
        System.debug('Connected');
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;

        //accountId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

        System.debug('Connected');
    }
}
```

I am getting nothing from Salesforce when i trigger the request from Slack. What am i doing wrong. 
I have already created a remote site settings.

The URL i used in Slack to make the POST request is: 
https://test.salesforce.com/services//test/accounts/

Thank you.

Comment: How are you handling authentication?

Comment: It looks like I have to enter the OAuth token to be able to do the POST request. But i do not see where that can be done in Slack.

Comment: Slack must have a way to do the OAuth flow.  This might help: http://www.dreamhouseapp.io/slack/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that controller is only handling `GET` requests but Slack is doing a `POST`.

Comment: I already catered for the POST request from Salesforce. But it is not connecting since i do not see where i could enter the OAuth Access Token.